# SUM If Value Type = value

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs

I have a Google Sheet for accounting and I need to create a function to SUM all values where the cell "type" has a value of "fijo" or "variable" so I can get stats of the total amount of "fijo" and "variable" counts. This is what i've tried:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do this function?

Link for doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBPB_IMNXaqOeN4o9FdcQJ6MogDA-RPbzlAtgmwNJeU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: you need "sumif" function

Comment: Added link for document. The idea is so it counts the total of "fijo" and total of "variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(E7:E40; REGEXMATCH(D7:D40; "Fijo|Variable")))
```

[image]

Comment: This did not work

Comment: @Charlie how come? whats your desired result?

Comment: @player0 Wait my bad, yes it is working. It does count all values with the type name. Thanks for the help man!